Blenderkit model of ocean has lots of noise
I download a model from Blenderkit of an ocean, and it has lots of noise, how can I fix this?
Im currently on 4.2 and will use EEVEE.




I do not have this ocean, but your viewport samples are set to 16. Maybe increase this value? Apart from that it also depends on the lighting in your scene etc.
